# Python PriorityQueue implementation, Attribute Error

Tags: python, priority-queue

Currently working on an assignment for my CS course and Ive run into a problem with my implementation of a PriorityQueue. First off, heres my **init** for the class:

```
class PriorityQueue(Container):
    
    def __init__(self, less_than):
        """Initialize this to an empty PriorityQueue.

        @type self: PriorityQueue
        @type less_than: Callable[[Object, Object], bool]
            Determines the relative priority of two elements of the queue.
            If x._less_than(y) is true, then x has higher priority than y.
        @rtype: None
        """

        self._queue = []
        self._less_than = less_than
```

However, when running doctests for my add method, I'm being returned an Attribute Error stating that str objects have no attribute _less_than. Ive spoken to my prof who brushed it off as, "probably just a typo" so after many hours mulling over this Ive turned to SO.

Heres the add method:

```
def add(self, item):
    if self._queue == []:
        self._queue.append(item)
    for i in range(len(self._queue)):
        if item._less_than(self._queue[i]):
            self._queue.insert(i, item)
```

And heres the error:

```
File ", line 99, in add
Failed example:
    pq.add('arju')
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/docrunner.py", line 140, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest add[3]>", line 1, in <module>
        pq.add('arju')
      File "", line 113, in add
    if item._less_than(self._queue[i]):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_less_than'
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you should not mutate `_queue` list while iterating through it

Comment: The `item` doesn't have a `_less_than`. The *priority queue* has a `_less_than`. You have other bugs, too.

Comment: You are passing a `str` to the `item` argument of `add`, right here: `pq.add('arju')`. Inside your add method, you use `item.__less_then(self._queue[i])`, but strings don't have that method... it's pretty clear from the error...

Comment: @Azat he's not iterating through the list, he's iterating through a range of integers which he then uses to access items by index.  That's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear:

```
if item._less_than(self._queue[i]):
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_less_than'
```

This obviously tells us that `_less_than` is not found on `item`.  And clearly `item` is of type `str`.  Since `_less_than` is a class member variable of the queue, not of an element of the queue, you need to invoke it on the queue, not the item.  Also, `_less_than` as per the documentation you posted takes two arguments, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Your add method should be something like this:

```
def add(self, item):
    if not self._queue:  # 1
        self._queue.append(item)
        return
    for i in range(len(self._queue)):
        if self._less_than(self._queue[i], item):   # 2
            self._queue.insert(i, item)
            return
    self._queue.append(item)  # 3
```

There are three things that need to be changed.

1. In your code you compare `self._queue` with a new, empty queue.  Instead you should take advantage of the fact that Python container objects have a Boolean value of `False` if they're empty.  When you insert the first item in the list, you are done and need to return; otherwise you will insert the same item a second time.
2. `_less_than` is a function.  It's assigned in the constructor so it's a member of `PriorityQueue`.  Its purpose is to compare two items.  So you need to call it with two items to be compared: one of them is the next item in the list, and the other is the new item to be inserted.  Once you have found the correct place to insert the new item, you insert it and you are done.  You must return at that point.
3. If the `_less_than` function returns `False` for every item already in the list, you need to add the item at the end.